# trying to make a text to binary converter - not working

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to make a text to binary converter in Python and I can't get the capital letter conversion to work.
The output for lower case `a` for example is 01100001 as it should be, but when I make it capital `A` it just says 01000000

```
inputStr = input("text: ")

alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

for i in inputStr:
    binary = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    if i == " ":
        binary[2] = 1
        for x in range(len(binary)):
            print (binary[x], end = "")
    else:
        low = i.islower()
        position = 0
        binary[1] = "1"
        if low:
            binary[2] = "1"
        for x in range(len(alphabet)):
            if alphabet[x] == i:
                position = x+1
        #intentially not elif statements
        if position - 16 >= 0:
            binary[3] = "1"
            position -= 16
        if position - 8 >= 0:
            binary[4] = "1"
            position -= 8
        if position - 4 >= 0:
            binary[5] = "1"
            position -= 4
        if position - 2 >= 0:
            binary[6] = "1"
            position -= 2
        if position - 1 >= 0:
            binary[7] = "1"
            position -= 1
        for x in range(len(binary)):
            print(binary[x], end = "")
```

Comment: What do you WANT the result to be for the character 'A'?  It looks like you want binary[2] to be a flag indicating whether the character is not upper case - is that true?  Do you want the code for 'A' to equal the code for 'a' otherwise?

Comment: Welcome. I find question posts on stack**overflow** (StackExchange in general) work well when closing with an explicit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if alphabet[x] == i.lower():` when comparing in line 15.

Answer (score 0):

If that's okay for you, you can use the built-in functions to solve your problem.

To convert a letter to its ASCII representation, use:

```
A_in_ASCII = ord('A') # 65
```

Then, to get the binary representation, use:

```
A_in_binary = bin(A_in_ASCII) # '0b1000001'
```

And then you can clean the output like this, by removing '0b' prefix and converting it to int:

```
output = int(A_in_binary[2:]) # 1000001
```